# Joining MySQL tables in a tricky way

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have three tables

table persons

```
id | name
```

table files

```
id | person_data | person_id
```

table items

```
id | item_name | file_id
```

Each person has multiple files and each file has multiple items. 
Is there any way to select for each person all it's items using just mysql returning something like this:

```
person - file_id -> item 1, file_id -> item 2, file_id -> item 3
```

I was thinking on some type of JOIN, i tried all combinations that i could imagine but i think that join it's not a solution, or...

Comment: `SELECT item_name FROM items JOIN files ON file_id = files.id JOIN persons ON person_id = persons.id WHERE persons.id = 1`?

Comment: I think you are looking for [Group Concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: @RocketHazmat i want to get all persons with all their items, and use the result in a loop like foreach person get all items

Answer (score 5):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`.Please check [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d947/1)

```
SELECT
  b.id,b.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(b.items SEPARATOR '|')
FROM (SELECT
        p.id,p.name,
        CONCAT(f.id,' -> ', GROUP_CONCAT(i.item_name)) AS items
      FROM persons p,
        files f,
        items i
      WHERE p.id = f.person_id
          AND f.id = i.file_id
      GROUP BY f.id) AS b
GROUP BY b.id
```

Comment: it't not the holy grail but i't the closest answer, i still need to further alter the returned result as the items come caoncatenated

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ti.id, ti.item_name
FROM TableItems ti
INNER JOIN TableFiles tf ON tf.id = ti.file_id
INNER JOIN TablePersons tp ON tp.id = tf.person_id
WHERE tp.id = :id
```

Where `:id` is the `id` of the person you want to list items for.

Comment: The `id` in your SELECT is ambiguous.

Comment: as i told @Rocket Hazmat, i want to get all persons with all their items in one query.